# Emit an event from child mount and access from parent mount

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have a component called `child`. I have data there that I want to access in my parent component. I want to emit an event in the `childs` mount: `this.$emit('get-data', this.data)` before finally retrieving it in the parent mount. Is this possible to do / practical? If it is how can one achieve it? If not, what are some better alternatives?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware if being able to listen for `$emit`'d data, from a child `mount()`, inside a parent `mount()`. You need to bind the listener to the child component within the parent template. Typical example using [SFC](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)

**Child.vue:**

```
export default{
   name: 'child',
   mount(){
     this.$emit('get-data', this.data);
   }
}
```

**Parent.vue:**

```
<template>
   <div>
      <child v-on:get-data="doSomething"></child>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
import Child from './Child';
export default{
   name: 'parent',
   components: { Child },
   methods(){
     doSomething(data){
       //Do something with data.
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to pass data from a child to a parent is scoped slots. I think that is more appropriate than events in your case (only pass data without any relation to a real event). But I'm not sure that I fully understood you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `created` hook not `mounted` because you only need access to reactive data and events. You could emit the whole child component and then drill into its data as needed.

template

```
<child-component @emit-event="handleEvent">
  {{ parentData }}
</child-component>
```

child

```
Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: '<div><slot/></div>',
  data() {
    return {
      childData: 'childData', 
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$emit('emit-event', this)
  }
})
```

parent

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    parentData: undefined,
  },
  methods: {
    handleEvent({ childData }) {
      this.parentData = childData
    }
  }
})
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caseyjoneal/f0v5qmny/38/)